# How to use masonry 3.0 with require and bower

Tags: require, jquery-masonry, bower

I install masonry 3.0 in my project, but got some error:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/get-style-property/get-style-property.js 404 (Not Found) require.js:1880
Uncaught Error: Script error for: get-style-property/get-style-property
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET http://localhost:3000/get-size.js 404 (Not Found) require.js:1880
Uncaught Error: Script error for: get-size
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET http://localhost:3000/.js 404 (Not Found) require.js:1880
Uncaught Error: Script error for: 
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
```

working on:

```
mac 10
bower 0.10
node 0.10.8
```

my bower.json:

```
{
  "name": "kethervideo",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "~2.0.3",
    "requirejs": "~2.1.5",
    "underscore": "~1.4.4",
    "masonry": "~3.0.3",
    "imagesloaded": "~3.0.1"
  }
}
```

my requirejs config:

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: 'bower_components/jquery/jquery'
        , underscore: 'bower_components/underscore/underscore'
        , eventEmitter: 'bower_components/eventEmitter/EventEmitter'
        , eventie: 'bower_components/eventie/eventie'
        , getSize: 'bower_components/get-size/get-size'
        , getStyleProperty: 'bower_components/get-style-property/get-style-property'
        , outlayerItem: 'bower_components/outlayerAmd/item'
        , outlayer: 'bower_components/outlayerAmd/outlayer'
        , masonry: 'bower_components/masonry/masonry'
        , imagesloaded: 'bower_components/imagesloaded/imagesloaded'

    }
    , shim:{
        "underscore": ["jquery"]
        , "masonry": ["jquery"]
        , "imagesloaded": ["jquery"]
    }
});
```

I don't know what's wrong with it , I include all packages what masonry need.

Answer (score 1):

Besides all the advices of the others i am not sure masonry is requirejs ready before version 3.1.
See here: https://github.com/desandro/masonry/issues/296#issuecomment-21685501

With 3.1 you can follow the instructions from here:

http://masonry.desandro.com/appendix.html

```
requirejs.config({
  paths: {
    eventie: 'bower_components/eventie',
    'doc-ready': 'bower_components/doc-ready',
    eventEmitter: 'bower_components/eventEmitter',
    'get-style-property': 'bower_components/get-style-property',
    'get-size': 'bower_components/get-size',
    'matches-selector': 'bower_components/matches-selector',
    outlayer: 'bower_components/outlayer',
    masonry: 'bower_components/masonry'
  }
});

requirejs( [ 'masonry/masonry' ], function( Masonry ) {
  new Masonry( /*...*/ )
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using camelCase paths, it seems they are with dashes in this case. Try them out and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the name of the keys in your path.

If you check the bottom of getSize.js you'll notice it does

```
define( [ 'get-style-property/get-style-property' ], defineGetSize );
```

It will check the config for an alias, and if it cant find one, then it will check the relative path; which is why you are getting 404 errors

changing your config to something like the below should fix the 404 errors

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: 'bower_components/jquery/jquery'
        , underscore: 'bower_components/underscore/underscore'
        , eventEmitter: 'bower_components/eventEmitter/EventEmitter'
        , eventie: 'bower_components/eventie/eventie'
        , 'get-size/get-size': 'bower_components/get-size/get-size'
        , 'get-style-property/get-style-property': 'bower_components/get-style-property/get-style-property'
        , outlayerItem: 'bower_components/outlayerAmd/item'
        , outlayer: 'bower_components/outlayerAmd/outlayer'
        , masonry: 'bower_components/masonry/masonry'
        , imagesloaded: 'bower_components/imagesloaded/imagesloaded'

    }
    , shim:{
        "underscore": ["jquery"]
        , "masonry": ["jquery"]
        , "imagesloaded": ["jquery"]
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the directory path in **.bowercc** file to "app/scripts" and do a **bower install**

Comment: Welcome to SO. As this is your first post, please consider add some link where OP can refer to do proposed steps.